# Lua Pattern: %b{}? optional balanced braces possible

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

I want to have optional balanced braces to be part of my match. Is that possible with just the normal patterns?
My Test Code looks like this:

```
for m in string.match('str{},str2{str3{}},str4,str5{a{}b{}}', '[^,]-%b{}') do
  print(v)
end
```

the output is:

```
str{}
str2{str3{}}
str5{a{}b{}}
```

the missing part is `str4`

I thought the pattern `[^,]-%b{}?` would do it but %bxy and ? are both pattern items so of course it does not work, but is there a way to do it anyway?

My workaround for now is:

```
local stored
for e in string.gmatch(str, '[^,]+') do
  if stored then
    e = stored .. ',' .. e
  end
  if string.match(e, '^[^{}]+$') or string.match(e, '^[^{}]*%b{}[^{}]*$') then
    print(e)
    stored = nil
  else
    stored = e
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you have `str5{a{},b{}}` in your string?

Comment: yes I could. I should've put that in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround is to replace commas inside braces with zeroes (and restore them after comma-splitting).

```
local str = 'str{},str2{str3{}},str4,str5{a{},b{}}'
for m in str:gsub('%b{}', function(b) return b:gsub(',', '\0') end):gmatch'[^,]+' do
   m = m:gsub('%z', ',')
   print(m)
end
```

Output:

```
str{}
str2{str3{}}
str4
str5{a{},b{}}
```

Comment: very elegant solution with that function argument. For better readablility I did split that line up but this solution is absolutly great.

Answer (score 3):

> %b{}? optional balanced braces possible

No. You'd need to split by comma and handle the way you did this.

One way to simplify may be to replace `([^}]),` with `\1{},` first and then apply your processing without any special cases.

Comment: I did actually think of that but I didnt know replacement accepts patterns. thank you. But before accepting your answer I will wait a day or two for other answers.

Comment: If you don't want to mess with pattern replacements, the frontier pattern may work too: `gsub("%f[},],","{},")`